# How to install npm after it uninstalled itself?

Tags: node.js, npm

I was recommended to run `sudo npm install -g npm` and so I did, now `npm` is gone!

It doesn't exist in the directory either `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`.

Is there a way to install it back?

edit

I have node installed `v14.17.0`

Comment: Have you opened a new window to see if it's just in a different path?  Ubuntu?

Comment: I opened a new terminal window (macbook) and ran npm and the same thing "command not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use NVM(nodejs version manager) simply by running this command :

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

and

```
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

now you can download any version of nodejs and use it into the single project or globally without problems

if you need to download any version you can do it by the comand :
`nvm install 14`

now you have npm and node 14, but if you need to use it into the project you can do it by the command : `nvm use 14`

now you can switch between node(or npm) versions without any problem

Comment: Would my current global npm packages work after I run the above?

Comment: yes of course...

Comment: So it would just install npm and not mess up anything else.

Comment: it was created specifically to handle these situations (different versions of node)

Answer (score 0):

`npm` comes with nodejs, you can just install nodejs using your OS.

See the link below

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Once you install nodejs, npm will be installed.

Comment: I already have node installed though. Orr does that not matter.

Comment: when I do `node -v` I get `v14.17.0`. Would re-installing it break anything (like a local mongo server or anything)